# C++ assignment operator for ROOT class

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator, root-framework

I'm using the ROOT frameowrk and I want to write a class the has a `TMultiGraph` member. I'm trying to write and assignment operator for my class  but I fail due to compilaton issues. The class `TMultiGraph` keeps it's assignment operator as `protected`.

The header for my class:

```
#include "../include/clipper.hpp"
#include "TMultiGraph.h"
#include "TColor.h"
#include "RtypesCore.h"

using namespace ClipperLib;

class ClipperDraw : protected TMultiGraph {

public:
    ClipperDraw() {}

    ClipperDraw& operator=(const ClipperDraw &c);

private:
    TMultiGraph mg;

};
```

The `.cpp` is:

```
ClipperDraw& ClipperDraw::operator=(const ClipperDraw &c)
{
    mg = c.mg;
    return *this;
}
```

When compiling I get this message:

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall `root-config --cflags` -I./include -O2  -c -o obj/ClipperDraw.o src/ClipperDraw.cpp
In file included from src/../include/ClipperDraw.h:12:0,
                 from src/ClipperDraw.cpp:8:
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/deepjetLinux3/include/TMultiGraph.h: In member function ‘ClipperDraw& ClipperDraw::operator=(const ClipperDraw&)’:
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/deepjetLinux3/include/TMultiGraph.h:47:17: error: ‘TMultiGraph& TMultiGraph::operator=(const TMultiGraph&)’ is protected
    TMultiGraph& operator=(const TMultiGraph&);
                 ^
src/ClipperDraw.cpp:26:5: error: within this context
  mg = c.mg;
     ^
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'obj/ClipperDraw.o' failed
make: *** [obj/ClipperDraw.o] Error 1
```

Comment: So you *inherit* from `TMultiGraph`, and also keep it as a *member variable*?

Comment: @i thougt it might help to make the operator compile

Comment: Well, it doesn't.

Comment: @CinCout what does?

Comment: if `TMultiGraph` has no public assignment operator then either because it cannot be assigned to or its bad design (wouldnt be a big surprise in root :P), in the first case ... well if it cannot be assigned to then you better dont work around that restriction

Comment: but hy it cant do that? I also tried to declare the `TMultiGraph` operator as a friend but it didnt help

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor and the copy assignment operator for `TMultiGraph` are both marked as protected.  That means you cannot assign a `TMultiGraph` to another `TMultiGraph`.  Inheritance won't help you as it doesn't change that fact.

What inheriting from `TMultiGraph` will do is allow to to make your own graph class that you can copy.  That would look like

```
class MyMultiGraph : public TMultiGraph {
    //...
public:
    MyMultiGraph& operator =(const MyMultiGraph& rhs)
    {
        TMultiGraph::operator=(rhs);
        // assign MyMultiGraph member here
    }
};
```

Comment: you mean you can't even write something like `TMultiGrpah m,n; m=n;`?

Comment: @proton Correct.  Since they are marked as protected only friends or classes that derive from it can access to functions.

Comment: so in my code im supposed to write - `mg = TMultiGraph::operator=(rhs.mg);`? how to change the operator I wrote?

Comment: @proton No.  That won't work.  You can't copy a `TMultiGraph`.  Your choices are derive from it and provide the functionality you want or store a pointer and copy the pointer.  Doing that latter though means all in copies share the same graph.

Comment: Can you explain you answer? i dont understand how it solves my problem.

Comment: @proton It really doesn't because your problem can't be solved how you want it.  You'll never be able to have  `TMultiGrpah m,n; m=n;`

Comment: i understand it now. i dont understand what alternative your answer provides.

Comment: @proton It allows you to make a class that has the functionality of `TMultiGraph` but lets you copy it.  It isn't a great solution because you have to write a function for every function `TMultiGraph` has and in those functions you have to call the corresponding `TMultiGraph` function.